# При попытке получить некоторые сайты requests.get() выдает ошибки

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

проблема такая. Пытаюсь получить какой-либо сайт используя `requests.get()`. Но с одними сайтами всё прекрасно работает(github.com), а с другими(vk.com, telegram.org, stackoverflow.com) происходит такая мистика. Буквально неделю назад ничего такого не было. Обновил библиотеки, использовал разные подключения интернета, но всё равно не заработало. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

```
>>>requests.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 815, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 314, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00A49690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ru.stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00A49690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 507, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ru.stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00A49690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера')))
```

Comment: А пробовали увеличить timeout соединения?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка 10060 означает, что ваш скрипт не смог подключиться к удаленному хосту. Обычно это возникает в результате сетевых проблем или неправильных настроек, например прокси.

Попробуйте для начала подключиться с консоли используя телнет либо запросить у провайдера, если блокирует данный адрес.

Так как ваш запрос полностью валидный, то дело не в коде.

Comment: У вас ошибка ProxyError \\\Cannot connect to proxy \\\. Вероятно, ваш прокси-сервер в тот момент не работал.